# How can I read a .raw file in a Fortran program?

Tags: image-processing, fortran

I'm working with a old finite element code in Fortran. It's a research project in university.

I have a file *.raw* that represents a image in 3D.

The data in *.raw* file is stores in *uint16*, or in *uint8*, and the total number of integers are know.

How can read this image to an array of integers in a Fortran program?

**Something like that**

```
allocate(imgarray(total_int))
call raw2array(filename,imgarray)
```

I'm currently using python to read the image, and convert it into a vector of integers. This vector is read in Fortran with a text file.

**In python**

```
imgarray = np.fromfile(fid, dtype=np.uint16,count=total_int,sep='')
```

But when reading files of more than *1000x1000x1000* integers the process becomes very slow.

The project requires that the image *.raw* be read in binary, within the program in Fortran as a subroutine that completes a vector.

How can I read this image (in binary) and convert it into a vector of integers using a subroutine in Fortran?

Comment: *But when reading files of more than 1000x1000x1000 integers the process becomes very slow.* I seriously doubt reading will be any faster in Fortran.

Comment: Did you try anything? Do you have any code we can build on? Is the file in Fortran order or C order? Read about **stream** access in Fortran.

Comment: @VladimirF Actually the code is in F90, I was wrong because I saw that the program is compiled with gfortran and linked with **mpi77** . The non-parallel version of the code is in F77.

Comment: Do not post any links, show the relevant code here. Did you do anything or you just want a complete solution from us? Do you know how data are read from an external file in Fortran in general? You need the **stream** access here. Then it can be a single `read` statement. Just try to do something yourself. Open as stream and do `read(unit) imgarray`. Report what happened.

Comment: @VladimirF thanks for your guidance. I do not want a complete solution from anyone.

Comment: @VladimirF thank you for your comments. I respond as I understand the questions and I think I have the answers. If something of this is delayed, in the same way the answer will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your compiler supports 16 bit integers and stream access it is as simple as this

```
   use iso_fortran_env
   implicit none
   integer(kind=INT16), allocatable::m(:,:,:)
   allocate(m(1000,1000,1000))
   open(100,file='test.raw',access='stream')
   read(100)m
   end
```

Comment: thanks this works, with some small changes I could read the .raw file.

Comment: the performance is very similar for both cases. For an image of 128x128x128 (uint16) both python and fortran took 1 second. For an image of 288x288x300 (uint8) python it takes 12 seconds while fortran 11.

Answer (score 0):

From the solution given by @agentp, the *.raw* file is read in a array as:

```
use iso_fortran_env
implicit none
integer(kind=INT16), allocatable::m(:)
integer total_int
total_int = 1000*1000*1000
allocate(m(total_int))
open(100,file='test.raw',access='stream')
read(100)m
```